# Should querySelector :checked work for lightning input type checkbox?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

`this.template.querySelector("lightning-input:checked")` is not returning a checked checkbox of type `<lightning-input type="checkbox">` - 
**Why is this?**

---

Example (see [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/oPn0_58_/13/edit)):

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Should querySelector :checked work for lightning input type checkbox?

No. `:checked` only works on native HTML `<option>` and `<input>` elements (for now). At this point, you'd need to use Array.prototype.find:

```
var selected = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input')].filter(input => input.checked);
```

I believe that it would be possible for this to be coded into the component (based on the specs), but probably isn't implemented yet. We have no idea when, or if, this would be implemented in the future.

See [Reflecting properties to attributes](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements#reflectattr) for a description of how it would work.

Comment: thanks for clarification and the useful link!

Comment: Should it be var selected = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input')].filter(input => input.checked);

Comment: @DebadyutiSil Yes, it should. I must have missed it. I wasn't nearly as well-versed in LWC as I am now :p

Answer (score 1):

I actually tried this and it worked.

```
let listCheckedBtns = this.template.querySelectorAll(`lightning-input[data-type='checkedButton'][checked]`);
```